# cloudfoundry/vcap several yeti tests failing

Tags: cloud-foundry, yeti

I've been doing nearly daily single OS builds of cloudfoundry/vcap now on Ubuntu 10.04.4.  The last successful completion of all steps listed at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap was on 12/4/12.  Since then, there's been one problem or another (vmc register was fixed around 12/17).

The current problem is with the yeti tests (step 5).  Any suggestions to resolve the errors would be greatly appreciated.

The 35 of 40 failures I've received are:

1) BVT::Spec::ServiceRebinding::RubySinatra Verify rebinding for postgresql Failure/Error: service = bind_service(service_manifest, app)

```
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (postgresql 9.0): t2wd4d1-postgresql
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/service_rebinding/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:71:in `rebind'
 # ./spec/service_rebinding/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:115:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 21:54:21 -0800)
```

2) BVT::Spec::ServiceRebinding::RubySinatra Verify binding postgresql to two applications
     Failure/Error: res.response_code.should == OK

```
   expected: 200
        got: 500 (using ==)
 # ./spec/service_rebinding/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:35:in `block in create_db_obj'
 # ./spec/service_rebinding/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:32:in `each'
 # ./spec/service_rebinding/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:32:in `create_db_obj'
 # ./spec/service_rebinding/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:100:in `bind_apps'
 # ./spec/service_rebinding/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 21:56:17 -0800)
```

3) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubyRack rack ruby 1.9 autostaging
     Failure/Error: bind_service(service_manifest, app)

```
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (redis 2.2): tze2msr-redis
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rack_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 21:57:12 -0800)
```

4) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubyRack services autostaging
     Failure/Error: bind_service(service_manifest, app)

```
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (mongodb 2.0): tpyrgfp-mongodb
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rack_spec.rb:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rack_spec.rb:41:in `each'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rack_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 21:59:12 -0800)
```

5) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::JavaGrails Start grails app and add some records
     Failure/Error: service = bind_service(MYSQL_MANIFEST, app)

```
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (mysql 5.1): tff07-mysql
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/java_grails_spec.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:03:08 -0800)
```

6) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::JavaSpring Spring Web Application specifying a Cloud Service and Data Source

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(MONGODB_MANIFEST, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (mongodb 2.0): ty9dvxf-mongodb
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/java_spring_spec.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:04:57 -0800)
```

7) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::JavaSpring Spring Web Application specifying a Service Scan and Data Source

```
 Failure/Error: @session.cleanup!
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to delete service (mysql 5.1): teghkb0-mysql
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:47:in `rescue in delete'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:42:in `delete'
 # ./lib/harness/cfsession.rb:146:in `block in cleanup!'
 # ./lib/harness/cfsession.rb:146:in `each'
 # ./lib/harness/cfsession.rb:146:in `cleanup!'
 # ./spec/autostaging/java_spring_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:07:41 -0800)
```

8) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::JavaSpring Spring Web Application using a local MongoDBFactory

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(MONGODB_MANIFEST, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (mongodb 2.0): t1o1xe3d-mongodb
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/java_spring_spec.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:12:17 -0800)
```

9) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::JavaSpring Spring Web Application using a local RedisConnectionFactory

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(REDIS_MANIFEST, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (redis 2.2): t60sql3-redis
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/java_spring_spec.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:13:57 -0800)
```

10) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::JavaSpring Spring Web Application using a local RabbitConnectionFactory

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(RABBITMQ_MANIFEST, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (rabbitmq 2.4): tgecyrt-rabbitmq
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/java_spring_spec.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:15:29 -0800)
```

11) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::JavaSpring Spring 3.1 Hibernate application using a local DataSource

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(MYSQL_MANIFEST, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (mysql 5.1): txbjvp7-mysql
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/java_spring_spec.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:18:41 -0800)
```

12) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::JavaSpring Spring Web application using Hibernate and mysql

```
 Failure/Error: app2.bind(service)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to bind Service: t10g3qwn-mysql to Application: t10g3qwn-hibernate_app
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:121:in `rescue in bind'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:115:in `bind'
 # ./spec/autostaging/java_spring_spec.rb:185:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:28:39 -0800)
```

13) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::JavaSpring Spring Roo application using mysql

```
 Failure/Error: app2.bind(service)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to bind Service: tupiy7x-mysql to Application: tupiy7x-roo_app
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:121:in `rescue in bind'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:115:in `bind'
 # ./spec/autostaging/java_spring_spec.rb:203:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:35:47 -0800)
```

14) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::JavaSpring Spring Web application using Hibernate and postgresql

```
 Failure/Error: service = bind_service(POSTGRESQL_MANIFEST, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (postgresql 9.0): t1eyhai1-postgresql
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/java_spring_spec.rb:213:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:40:33 -0800)
```

15) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubySinatra services autostaging

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(service_manifest, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (redis 2.2): tqm94mh-redis
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:23:in `each'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:42:17 -0800)
```

16) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubySinatra Sinatra AMQP autostaging

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(service_manifest, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (rabbitmq 2.4): tyrqzgv-rabbitmq
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:43:09 -0800)
```

17) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubySinatra Autostaging with unsupported client versions

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(item[:service], app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (rabbitmq 2.4): t1e3hlxl-rabbitmq
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:58:in `each'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:45:43 -0800)
```

18) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubySinatra Autostaging with unsupported carrot version

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(service_manifest, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (rabbitmq 2.4): t1cmmfg6-rabbitmq
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:46:26 -0800)
```

19) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubySinatra Sinatra opt-out of autostaging via cf-runtime gem

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(service_manifest, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (redis 2.2): tddh45o-redis
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_sinatra_spec.rb:89:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:47:26 -0800)
```

20) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubyRails3 Rails autostaging

```
 Failure/Error: service_manifests.each { |manifest| services << create_service(manifest) }
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (mongodb 2.0): t1c3957g-mongodb
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rails3_spec.rb:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rails3_spec.rb:62:in `each'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rails3_spec.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:51:53 -0800)
```

21) BVT::Spec::Simple::RailsConsole::RubyRails3 rails test console tab completion

```
 Failure/Error: run_console(app.name)
 VMC::Client::HTTPException:
   HTTP exception: RestClient::RequestTimeout:Request Timeout
 # ./spec/simple/rails_console/rails_console_helper.rb:9:in `block in run_console'
 # ./spec/simple/rails_console/rails_console_helper.rb:7:in `times'
 # ./spec/simple/rails_console/rails_console_helper.rb:7:in `run_console'
 # ./spec/simple/rails_console/ruby_rails_spec.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:55:34 -0800)
```

22) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubyRails3 Rails opt-out of autokstaging via cf-runtime gem

```
 Failure/Error: app.push(services)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to bind Service: te6r46e-mysql to Application: te6r46e-rails_autoconfig_disabled_by_gem
   Request Timeout
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:121:in `rescue in bind'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:115:in `bind'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:45:in `block in push'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:45:in `each'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:45:in `push'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rails3_spec.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:57:25 -0800)
```

23) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::NodeNode Node.js version 0.4 autostaging

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(service_manifest, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (mongodb 2.0): t1uzed69-mongodb
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/node_node_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/autostaging/node_node_spec.rb:25:in `each'
 # ./spec/autostaging/node_node_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 22:59:46 -0800)
```

24) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubyStandalone standalone ruby18 autostaging
     Failure/Error: bind_service(service_manifest, app)

```
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (mongodb 2.0): t1qynqo3-mongodb
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_standalone_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_standalone_spec.rb:23:in `each'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_standalone_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:02:21 -0800)
```

25) BVT::Spec::Simple::RailsConsole::RubyRails3 rails test console rake tasks with ruby 1.9

```
 Failure/Error: app = create_push_app("rails_console_19_test_app")
 RuntimeError:
   Start App: t1ptg2te-rails_console_19_test_app failed.
   Request Timeout
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:104:in `rescue in start'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:100:in `start'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:46:in `push'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:48:in `create_push_app'
 # ./spec/simple/rails_console/ruby_rails_spec.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:17:21 -0800)
```

26) BVT::Spec::Simple::RubyGems::RubySinatra sinatra test deploy app with Gemfile.lock containing Windows versions

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service(POSTGRESQL_MANIFEST, app)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (postgresql 9.0): t13yx454-postgresql
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:22:26 -0800)
```

27) BVT::Spec::Simple::Python2Django Deploy Django Application

```
 Failure/Error: app = create_push_app("simple_django_app")
 RuntimeError:
   Application: t3c135x-simple_django_app cannot be started in 60 seconds
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:391:in `check_application'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:106:in `start'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:46:in `push'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:48:in `create_push_app'
 # ./spec/simple/python2_django_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:24:53 -0800)
```

28) BVT::Spec::Simple::RubyRails3 access my application root and see it's running version

```
 Failure/Error: @app = create_push_app("app_rails_version")
 RuntimeError:
   Start App: t6erk05-app_rails_version failed.
   Request Timeout
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:104:in `rescue in start'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:100:in `start'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:46:in `push'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:48:in `create_push_app'
 # ./spec/simple/ruby_rails3_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:29:25 -0800)
```

29) BVT::Spec::Simple::JavaStandalone standalone with java runtime

```
 Failure/Error: response.should =~ /Java version: #{version}/
   expected: /Java version: 1.6/
        got: "" (using =~)
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -/Java version: 1.6/
   +""
 # ./spec/simple/java_standalone_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:30:38 -0800)
```

30) BVT::Spec::Simple::PhpStandalone standalone with php runtime

```
 Failure/Error: response.should =~ /Hello from VCAP/
   expected: /Hello from VCAP/
        got: "PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imagick.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0\nPHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imap.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0\nPHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0\n" (using =~)
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
   -/Hello from VCAP/
   +PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imagick.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
   +PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/imap.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
   +PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
 # ./spec/simple/php_standalone_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:33:20 -0800)
```

31) BVT::Spec::AutoStaging::RubyRails3 Rails opt-out of autostaging via config file

```
 Failure/Error: service_manifests.each { |manifest| services << create_service(manifest) }
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (redis 2.2): til3qet-redis
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rails3_spec.rb:84:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rails3_spec.rb:84:in `each'
 # ./spec/autostaging/ruby_rails3_spec.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:34:55 -0800)
```

32) BVT::Spec::Simple::RailsConsole::RubyRails3 rails test console Postgres connection

```
 Failure/Error: app = create_push_app("rails_console_19_test_app")
 RuntimeError:
   Start App: t130kttg-rails_console_19_test_app failed.
   Request Timeout
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:104:in `rescue in start'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:100:in `start'
 # ./lib/harness/app.rb:46:in `push'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:48:in `create_push_app'
 # ./spec/simple/rails_console/ruby_rails_spec.rb:166:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:37:18 -0800)
```

33) BVT::Spec::Canonical::JavaSpring spring test redis service

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service_and_verify(app, REDIS_MANIFEST)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (redis 2.2): t18f6yaz-redis
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/canonical/canonical_helper.rb:12:in `bind_service_and_verify'
 # ./spec/canonical/java_spring_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:39:33 -0800)
```

34) BVT::Spec::Canonical::NodeNode node test rabbitmq service

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service_and_verify(@app, RABBITMQ_MANIFEST)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (rabbitmq 2.4): t16w1p05-rabbitmq
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/canonical/canonical_helper.rb:12:in `bind_service_and_verify'
 # ./spec/canonical/node_node_spec.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:40:58 -0800)
```

35) BVT::Spec::Canonical::RubyRack rack test mysql service

```
 Failure/Error: bind_service_and_verify(@app, MYSQL_MANIFEST)
 RuntimeError:
   Fail to create service (mysql 5.1): t1du436k-mysql
   target failed to handle our request due to an internal error (502)
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:33:in `rescue in create'
 # ./lib/harness/service.rb:28:in `create'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:18:in `create_service'
 # ./lib/harness/scripts_helper.rb:23:in `bind_service'
 # ./spec/canonical/canonical_helper.rb:12:in `bind_service_and_verify'
 # ./spec/canonical/ruby_rack_spec.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 (Failure time: 2012-12-18 23:46:08 -0800)
```

Comment: that is a really long post.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  I just wanted to show the failure messages.  I am sure that there is one or two root issues.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your yeti repo hash? And your command to execute yeti tests?

By default yeti uses 10 threads to run tests, you can add [n] to specify thread number. I am not sure if your environment can support 10 threads in parallel, please try `bundle exec rake full[4]` (or [2] or even [1])

And for the failures, you can also run `bundle exec rake rerun[1]` to rerun the failures.